# Keras filter_length keyword in 2.X?

Tags: keras

I'm pretty new to Keras and I realize that there are a lot of tutorials out there using using older versions of the API that has been deprecated. It not straight forward (at least not to) how to map old parameter inputs to new ones. I found a lot of help in the 2.0 release notes, especially for a lot of the inputs to convolutional layers.

One thing I haven't found is filter_length. What´s the new keyword for that?

Comment: It's `kernel_size`.

Comment: In General, what you always can do is check in the GitHub repository of Keras. in your case in the [`convolutional.py`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/keras-2/keras/layers/convolutional.py) file. In the top left corner, you are able to switch branches btw. keras-1 and keras-2 and see which term is equivalent to which new term.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Want to write an answer?

Comment: Sure, I should've put it in an answer in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `kernel_size` (repeating my answer in the comment so that this question won't be marked as "unanswered").
As mentioned by McLawrence, checking the source code is a good idea when comparing different versions.

In Keras 2, the arguments of 1D-, 2D- and 3D-convolution layers have been unified. They no longer have separate namings for an identical concept (e.g., `nb_row`/`nb_col` in the old `Convolution2D` layer is just `filter_length` in a higher dimension).